# Referencing .d.ts files in a custom LanguageServiceHost

Tags: typescript

I am implementing a Typescript compiler that is going to be called very frequently and needs to compile single Typescript files quickly. I have followed this guide for setting up an in memory compiler: http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/01/20/typescript-compiler-api.html.
The TS file I am compiling has several imports for things like jQuery which I have TSD files for.

typescriptCompile.ts

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as ts from 'typescript';

class MyLanguageServiceHost implements ts.LanguageServiceHost {
    files: { [fileName: string]: { file: ts.IScriptSnapshot; ver: number } } = {};

    log = _ => { };
    trace = _ => { };
    error = _ => { };
    getCompilationSettings = ts.getDefaultCompilerOptions;
    getScriptIsOpen = _ => true;
    getCurrentDirectory = () => "";
    getDefaultLibFileName = _ => "lib";

    getScriptVersion = fileName => this.files[fileName].ver.toString();
    getScriptSnapshot = fileName => this.files[fileName].file;

    getScriptFileNames(): string[] {
        var names: string[] = [];
        for (var name in this.files) {
            if (this.files.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                names.push(name);
            }
        }
        return names;
    }

    addFile(fileName: string, body: string) {
        var snap = ts.ScriptSnapshot.fromString(body);
        snap.getChangeRange = _ => undefined;
        var existing = this.files[fileName];
        if (existing) {
            this.files[fileName].ver++;
            this.files[fileName].file = snap
        } else {
            this.files[fileName] = { ver: 1, file: snap };
        }
    }
}

var host = new MyLanguageServiceHost();
var languageService = ts.createLanguageService(host, ts.createDocumentRegistry());

const includeFiles = [
    'es6-promise.d.ts',
    'jquery-3.1.1.d.ts',
    'twemoji-2.2.4.d.ts'
];

includeFiles.forEach(file => host.addFile('types/' + file, fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'types', file)).toString()));

export function compile(code: string) {
    host.addFile(`code.ts`, code);

    var output = languageService.getEmitOutput("code.ts").outputFiles[0].text;

    console.log(output);
}
```

code to compile

```
import * as twemoji from 'twemoji-2.2.4';

export const test = twemoji.parse('test');
```

The language service throws an error trying to access the script `twemoji-2.2.4.ts` rather than `twemoji-2.2.4.ts`. How can I register the definitions with the language service/compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have partially found an answer that is enough to cover my use case.  I have added the following to `MyLanguageServiceHost`:

```
resolveModuleNames = (moduleNames: string[], containingFile: string): ts.ResolvedModule[] => {
    return moduleNames.map(name => {
        return {
            resolvedFileName: name + '.d.ts',
        }
    });
};
```

This resolves all modules to their `.d.ts` form which is what I needed.  I'm still not sure of how to handle this if you have a mix of definitions and source files.